# How to use Spark RDD to make batch submit?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have RDD of lots of items, just  simplify it likes:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and submit those items to batch API(`API.post(a[])`). but API limits max batch(exp. 3).
So for the best performance,  I need to transform RDD iterator into the limit  Array as possible:

```
[[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [9]]
```

and I use Spark  Java to push the data to API.

```
rdd.foreach(a -> { API.post(a)}
```

My question is how to transform it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, there is no RDD iterator but an iterator for each partition. To access them, `foreachPartition` can be used and then batching the iterator can be done with plain old Java iterator ops. Here is a solution using the Spark Java API http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#foreachPartition-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction- and Guava:

```
rdd.foreachPartition(it -> 
  Iterators.partition(it, batchSize)
           .forEachRemaining(API::post));
```